# flatten in prolog - something like else

Tags: prolog

Look at my implementation of flatten :  Generally, it is working.  Only problem is for `my_flatten([], F)` - it gives `F=[]; F=[[]]` instead of `F=[]`.

```
my_flatten(L, X) :-
   my_flatten(L, X, []). %, reverse(F, X).

my_flatten([], Acc, Acc).
my_flatten([H|T], F, Acc) :-
   my_flatten(H, F1, Acc),
   my_flatten(T, F, F1), !.                         
my_flatten(X, [X|Acc], Acc).
```

For `my_flatten(X, [1,2,3])` this program loops - it is OK, because there exist infinitely many answers, as: `[[],[],[],[],1,2,3]`.
However, the same problem as above - for `my_flatten(X, [])` it should be also looping, but gives `[]; [[]]`.

Moreover result is reverser - but I don't care about it - if I uncomment `reverse` it will be OK - but then instead of looping mentioned above it returns `false`.

Can you help me change this code in such way that it returns `[]` for `my_flatten([], X)` ?

I implemented suggestions of @lurker:

```
my_flatten(L, F) :-
   my_flatten(L, X, []),
   reverse(F, X).

my_flatten([], Acc, Acc).
my_flatten([H|T], F, Acc) :- 
   is_list(H), 
   my_flatten(H, F1, Acc),
   my_flatten(T, F, F1).
my_flatten([X|T], F, Acc) :-
   not(is_list(X)),
   my_flatten(T, F, [X|Acc]).
```

Comment: You seem to have an affinity for the cut operator (`!`). ;)  Having the first argument be a list sometimes and sometimes not has a funny code smell to me. `my_flatten(X, [X|Acc], Acc)` looks problematic with `Acc` appearing in those two places. What `my_flatten/3` means logically is unclear. Note that `is_list(H)` is true if `H` is a list, so you can use that if you find it handy.

Comment: Ok, I am brother of cut operator, however you are enemy for cut operator :D   Thanks for hints. I added to my first post new solution. What do you think about it ?

Comment: The cut has it's place, but it's not good to use it to try to "fix" a problem. Many beginners use it for various purposes, often to patch an issue along the way, but end up destroying the proper generality of their predicate. I am a friend of cut, too, but only in cases where it is properly purposed. :)

Comment: `is_list/1` is a very ill-chosen predicate. It succeeds for `L = [], is_list(L)` and fails for `is_list(L), L = []`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before I answer your actual question, I have one comment on using `flatten/2`:

**Don't**.

Reason: `flatten/2` is not a true relation. For example, we have:

```
?- X = [a], flatten(X, Ls).
X = [a],
Ls = [a].
```

but:

```
?- flatten(X, Ls), X = [a].
X = [a],
Ls = [[a]].
```

This obviously makes no sense from a logical point of view.

Please, use `append/2` instead to remove precisely *one level* of nesting, and try implementing *that*.

Hint: Use [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)!

I know that `flatten/2` is shown or asked for in many Prolog courses. That doesn't mean that it's useful, valuable, instructive or anything like that.

Now, to your actual question:

Always also try the most general query:

```
?- my_flatten(X, Ls).
X = Ls, Ls = [] ;
X = [[]],
Ls = [].
```

Start taking it from there: Is this answer **too general**, **too specific** or *both*? Think about this.

Then, think about what must hold about the arguments for this to even make sense, i.e., under what conditions can we even give sound answers that cannot be rendered non-sensical with further instantiations?

It will help you to read about [instantiation-error](/questions/tagged/instantiation-error) in Prolog.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Did you see a new solution ? I edited my first post (using suggestions of @lurker) and created working solution. What do you think about it ?

Comment: Still no cigar: `?- my_flatten([[X]], Ls), X = [a].` succeeds with `Ls = [[a]]`, which is not flattened. In cases where you cannot guarantee sound results, you should throw an [tag:instantiation-error].

Comment: So help me correct it to deal with such cases, please.

Comment: As I said, you need to throw instantiation errors if the arguments are not yet sufficiently instantiated. You need extra-logical predicates like `var/1` and `ground/1` for such tests. Check out `library(error)` in SWI-Prolog for more inspiration. Also, I strongly recommend you simply forget about `flatten/2`: It is inherently not monotonic, and if you ever need this predicate, you have misdesigned your data structures. All usages of `flatten/2` I have seen so far should have been handled by simply using `append/2` instead.

Comment: Isn't just using `functor/3` good enough to produce instantiation errors in this case?

Comment: Yes it is. It's also one of these extra-logical predicates.

Comment: @mat: Why is functor/3 extra-logical? It does model faithfully a relation (and produces errors for difficult cases).

Comment: Well, at least we cannot implement `functor/3` with a (finite) first-order program. Otherwise, yes, it's a relation.

Comment: My dear collegues, I wrote this `flatten` only for practise purposes. @mat told me that I should handle instantiation errors. Only such case is when both arguments are variables, yeah ?   What does mean extra-logical  ? Beyond firt order logic ?